# Is the closure of the intersection of a set with a closed subspace is equal to the closure of the set intersection the subspace?

Tags: general-topology

If $M$ is a closed subspace of a topological vector space $X$ and $A$ intersects $M$. Is $\overline{A\cap M}=\overline{A}\cap M$

Comment: If $A$ can be arbitrary, in general the two aren't equal. If there are restrictions on $A$, those might force equality.

Comment: I mean for any subset $A$ which intersects the closed subspace $M$

Comment: Then no. Consider $A = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(x,0) : x \geqslant 1\}$ and $M = \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ for a simple example.